# Stripe -- Customer's default payment method is not in the card object

Tags: javascript, express, stripe-payments

I've an issue with how to organize my code and haven't been able to figure out how to solve this issue for the past 48 hrs. My brain basically is stuck and I'd like help how to figure out the solution. I'm using expressjs for the server and Svelte for the front.

The issue :
I'm able to create customers, paymentMethods, paymentIntents and attach the paymentMethod to customer, set the said paymentMethod as the default paymentMethod to its customer...etc

To display the customer paymentmethods I have to use Stripe.paymentMethods.list which returns an array of cards. The card object doesn't include any field indicating that the card is the default payment method for the customer.

The default_payment_method which stores the default paymentmethod is in the customer object. So I need to get the customer object and this is where I need help. How to do I solve this problem, how to access the Stripe.paymentMethods.list() to get the list of cards and stripe.customer.retrieve() so I have access to the defaultpaymentmethod in my serverhandle so I can return all that information to the front?

```
// get cards
stripe.paymentMethods.list({
        customer: customer,
        type: 'card'
    }).then(cards => {
        //I can return cards but not customer
        return res.end(JSON.stringify({ cards: cards}));
        }).catch(err => { console.log("err message :", err.message)});
});    

// now get customer
stripe.customers.retrieve(
  'cus_Ib01d7QtMdz2ez'
).then(customer=>{ 
      // I can return customer but not cards
     return res.end(JSON.stringify({customer : customer}));
});

// next step, send customer and cards to the frontst 

return res.end(JSON.Stringfy({cards : cards; customer : customer}))
    ?????
```

How to return "cards and customer" objects so I can show the customer his/her cards and which one is the default payment method. How to use res.end(JSON.stringfy({}))
with the two seperate functions, can I combine them both and return one return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're 80% of the way there. You definitely can return both object, though I might recommend only returning the specific bits of info you need. Instead of responding in a `.then()` block, use `async/await` to get both responses.

```
const cards = await stripe.paymentMethods.list({
    customer: 'cus_123',
    type: 'card'
})

const customer = stripe.customers.retrieve(
  'cus_123'
)

return res.send(JSON.Stringify({cards : cards, customer : customer}))
// or, send json directly
// return res.json({cards : cards, customer : customer})
```

(Also, note I replaced the semi-colon `;` with a comma `,` and correct the typo):

`return res.end(JSON.String**i**fy({cards : cards**,** customer : customer}))`

Comment: Thank you. It works. I ended up with two server handlers to return each object and I combined them on the front but it was a lot of work. Now I know how to do it the easy way :) ... I try to use async/await more but I'm still not 100% aware of the benefit.  The asterisks were appreciated--after staring at the screen for so long, I won't be able to locate my typo (I wrote that question so frustrated and I didn't pay attention to what I was typing) ...Big thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped :)